# Most wierd loss function shape (because of weight decay parameter)

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, loss-function

I am training a large neural network model (1 module Hourglass) for a facial landmark recognition task. Database used for training is WFLW.

Loss function used is *MSELoss()* between the predicted output heatmaps, and the ground-truth heatmaps.

```
- Batch size = 32
- Adam Optimizer
- Learning rate = 0.0001
- Weight decay = 0.0001
```

As I am building a baseline model, I have launched a basic experiment with the parameters shown above. I previously had executed a model with the same exact parameters, but with `weight-decay=0`. The model converged successfully. Thus, the problem is with the weight-decay new value.

I was expecting to observe a smooth loss function that slowly decreased. As it can be observed in the image below, the loss function has a very very wierd shape.

[image: Loss function]

This will probably be fixed by changing the weight decay parameter (decreasing it, maybe?).
I would highly appreciate if someone could provide a more in-depth explanation into the strange shape of this loss function, and its relation with the *weight-decay* parameter.

In addition, to explain why this premature convergence into a very specific value of 0.000415 with a very narrow standard deviation? Is it a strong local minimum?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Loss should not consistently increase when using gradient descent. It does not matter if you use weight decay or not, there is either a bug in your code (e.g. worth checking what happens with normal gradient descent, not Adam, as there are ways in which one can wrongly implement weight decay with Adam), or your learning rate is too large.